# android button source code only have four constructors,but why it is powerful

Tags: android

i look at the source code of the button, it extends TextView, and only have four constructors
 and two methods,  but it looks more powerful than TextView,why?

Comment: It's just in Buttons hormones.

Answer (score 1):

A `TextView` has already all the functionality of a `Button`. The only difference is the styling, mainly the background drawable.

The different default style is set in the two arg constructor:

```
public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.buttonStyle);
}
```